# Проверить, что переменной типа Integer было присвоено значение

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi проверить, что `Integer` переменной было ранее присвоено какое либо значение ?

Comment: возможно if myVar != null, или подробнее напишите вопрос

Comment: В Integer до присваивания не null, а какое то рандомное значение.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

По-настоящему - никак. Integer не хранит нигде никакой дополнительной информации, кроме тех 4 байт что на него выделено.

Конечно, вы можете присвоить переменной какое-либо "волшебное" значение, которое никогда не встречается в ваших данных (например `-1`, или `MaxInt`, или `777777`). *И в простом приложении я бы так и сделал.* Но однажды такое значение может вам встретиться и программа даст сбой.

Также можно использовать другой готовый тип данных, типа `Variant`.

Более правильный вариант - хранить информацию о присвоении в другой переменной, например `IsIntegerAssigned: Boolean;` и поддерживать ее состояние при каждой операции. Но это более громоздко и неудобно.

Современный вариант - можно положить обе переменных в `record` и переопределить присвоение, примерно так:

```
TMyInteger = record
private
  fValue: Integer;
  fIsChanged: Boolean;
public
  // Присвоение Integer
  class operator Implicit(const A: Integer): TMyInteger;
  // Чтение значения. Не помню, можно ли так же через неявную конвертацию или нет
  property Value: Integer read fValue;
  property IsChanged: Boolean read fIsChanged;
  // Тут еще надо переопределить конструктор New, который будет заполнять поля нулями
  // А можно сделать fIsChanged: string; тогда поле будет пустым при первом обращении)
end;

....

class operator TMyInteger.Implicit(const A: Integer): TMyInteger;
begin
  Result.fValue := A;
  Result.fIsChanged := True;
end;

I := TMyInteger.New;
I := 45;
Assert(I.IsChanged, 'I is changed');
```

Ну и конечно убер-вариант - положить в класс.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать вторую переменную потом сравнивайте примерно так

```
myInt: Integer;
myVar: Integer;

if  myInt==myVar  then
begin
     // он не изменился 
else 
  // он изменился сохраняем новое значение 
   myVar := myInt;
end;
```